# Python append loop issue

Tags: python

I would like to append rows to a dataframe using a loop, but I can't figure out how not to overwrite the previously appended rows.

Example of starting dataframe

```
print df 
    quantity  cost
 0         1    30
 1         1     5
 2         2    10
 3         4     8
 4         5     2
```

My goal is

```
    quantity  cost
 0         1    30
 1         1     5
 2         2    10
 3         4     8
 4         5     2
 5         2    10
 6         4     8
 7         4     8
 8         4     8
 9         5     2
 10        5     2
 11        5     2
 12        5     2
```

My current code is incorrect (only appending rows with quantity==5), but I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
  for x in xrange(2,6):
       data = df['quantity'] == x
       data = df[data]
       df_new = df.append([data]*(x-1),ignore_index=True)
```

Any advice would be awesome, thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you want? I don't see what you mean by overwriting, and it sees to be appending rows where `quantity` == 2, 4, and 5, (x-1) times... which seem to be *exactly* what you wrote.

Comment: How to correct my code to get the goal df I included

Comment: Ah. Yes, because you need to use `df_new.append` Or else every time you use `df_new = df.append(...)` it overwrites.

Comment: No the output from that code does not include the appended rows for quantity == 2 and 4, it only appends rows with quantity == 5 on the original dataframe

Comment: yes, I was mistaken because I thought the output the OP showed was the ouput, not the expected output.

Comment: Oh perfect, thank you!